# Request method 'HEAD' not supported

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I run a new instance of Intellij Idea with apache tomcat 7.0.55 and I've created a new simple project but i get this errors continually :

```
Feb 28, 2015 11:54:13 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'HEAD' not supported
```

**Controller:**

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/",method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>untitled</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>untitled</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At class level, with

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
public class HelloController {
```

you declare that your controller will process `GET` and `HEAD` requests for root URL `/`.

But at method level,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

you only accept `GET` requests. Spring is right, *Request method 'HEAD'* is *not supported*.

You should either accept everything at method level (`@RequestMapping(value = "")` ), or create a second method to process `HEAD` requests.

Comment: In which scenario  we can use RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD ?

Answer (score 0):

in recent spring releases, GET method implicitly adds HEAD method.

`@GetMapping (and @RequestMapping(method=HttpMethod.GET)) are implicitly mapped to and support HTTP HEAD. An HTTP HEAD request is processed as if it were HTTP GET except that, instead of writing the body, the number of bytes are counted and the Content-Length header is set.`
For more details refer to : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-requestmapping.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-head-options